# How to centrally align the hint and drawable in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to align the `drawable` and hint at center in `EditText`. For that I am having this piece of code,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/icon"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now as soon as user starts typing, the `drawable` should move to extreme left of `EditText`. How to achieve this?

Comment: Probably you may need to override the EditText class and redraw...

Comment: Your drawable is not in center. It is at the left. Your `EditText` is `wrap_content` so it seems as if it is in the center.

Comment: Then how to achieve it w/o making wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:layout_gravity="center**" for your EditText. This will help you setting hint in center.

and for drawable this is hack. Set your drawableTop for editText and give some paddingTop to the view.

Comment: my hint and drawable are already in center.I want to move the drawable to left,as soon as user types in.

Comment: change it's position via code. Do it in on onTextChange listener . You cannot achieve it via xml.

Comment: then you need to implement **onTextChangeListener** for you **EditText**. and set drawables at runtime using **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)**

Comment: @stackLearner have you tried my answer as above suggested in comment?